# Метод splice() работает в js но не подтягивает html в Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular

Проблема вот в чем.Есть обычный массив значений, и я хочу удалить определенное значение,перед этим вызвав модальное окно с подтверждением удаления. Без подключения модального окна,строка удаляется и методом splice() сразу очищается с html-страницы

```
  public openDeleteModal(name: any, id: any) {
this.dialog.open(DeleteDialog, { data: { name, id } });       
}
 public fileDelete(id) { 
return this.http.delete(this.Url + '/delete' + id).subscribe(
  data => {

    console.log("DELETE Request is successful ", data);
    const index = this.myResults.findIndex(item => item.idPres == id);
    this.myResults.splice(index, 1);
  },
  error => {
    console.log("Error", error);
  })  
}
```

При испольовании модального окна,оно тоже удаляет,НО запись со страницы исчезает только после F5

```
@Component({
selector: 'list-files-deletedialog',
templateUrl: './list-files-deletedialog.component.html',
})
export class DeleteDialog {
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DeleteDialog>,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, private fileservice: FileService) 
{ }
public accept(): void {
this.fileservice.fileDelete(this.data.id);  
this.dialogRef.close();  
 }
close(): void {
this.dialogRef.close();
 }
 }
```

HTML главной страницы

```
 <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let myResult of myResults;">
    <td>{{ myResult.idPres }}</td>
    <td> {{ myResult.namePres }} </td>
    <td><button type="button" id="details" class="btn btn-info" (click)="openModal(myResult.descPres,myResult.namePres )">Details</button></td>
    <td><button type="button" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="openDeleteModal(myResult.namePres,myResult.idPres)">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

HTML popup'а

```
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="close()">
 <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
 <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Deletion</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  <p>Do you want to delete file : " {{data.name}} " ?</p>
  </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
    (click)="close()">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
   (click)="accept()">Ok</button>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что не нужно делать `splice` в сервисе, массив имеет отношение только к компоненту.

Будем вызывать метод `fileDelete` после закрытия диалогового окна и только если юзер кликнет `accept`:

```
// delete-dialog.component.ts

public accept(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close({
        accepted: true,
        id: this.data.id
    });
}
```

Убираем из кода метода сервиса `subscribe` и дальнейшую работу с массивом:

```
public fileDelete(id): Promise<Object> { 
    return this.http.delete(this.Url + '/delete' + id).toPromise();
}
```

Делаем подписку на `afterClosed` в компоненте:

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators/take';

this.dialog.open(DeleteDialog, { data: { name, id } }).afterClosed().pipe(
    take(1)
).subscribe((data) => {
    if (!data || !data.accepted) {
        return;
    }

    this.fileService.fileDelete(data.id).then(() => {
        // колбек в `then` сработает если файл удалится удачно
        // вызываем `splice` только в компоненте, а не в сервисе
        const index = this.myResults.findIndex(item => item.idPres == data.id);
        this.myResults.splice(index, 1);
    });
});
```